# Create multiple page in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have ssrs report with line# parameter. each line has barcode and I design form for each line to display the barcode. now the user need to print multiple forms for mulitple lines. how I can let SSRS generate page for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by line number and page break on group.